# LINQ NullReferenceException on a simple selection

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

The following code throws a NullReferenceException. If I filter user table using another column, exception is not throwed. DateTime type columns cause this exception.

```
using (MyDataContext dc = new MyDataContext())
    {
        var ids = dc.Users.Where(c => c.BirthDate < DateTime.Now.AddYears(-10)).Select(c => c.UserId);

        var list = (from c in dc.Users
                    where ids.Contains(c.UserId)
                    select c).ToList();
    }
```

Stack trace like this:

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]


System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlFactory.Member(SqlExpression expr, MemberInfo member) +182
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitMemberAccess(MemberExpression ma) +260
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner(Expression node) +939
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.Visit(Expression node) +18
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitExpression(Expression exp) +18
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression mc) +1011
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner(Expression node) +1003
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.Visit(Expression node) +18
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitExpression(Expression exp) +18
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitChangeType(Expression expression, Type type) +12
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitCast(UnaryExpression c) +117
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner(Expression node) +619
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.Visit(Expression node) +18
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitExpression(Expression exp) +18
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitBinary(BinaryExpression b) +35
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner(Expression node) +427
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.Visit(Expression node) +18
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitExpression(Expression exp) +18
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitBinary(BinaryExpression b) +35
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner(Expression node) +427
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.Visit(Expression node) +18
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitExpression(Expression exp) +18
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitWhere(Expression sequence, LambdaExpression predicate) +125
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitSequenceOperatorCall(MethodCallExpression mc) +3403
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression mc) +74
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner(Expression node) +1003
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.Visit(Expression node) +18
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitSelect(Expression sequence, LambdaExpression selector) +17
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitSequenceOperatorCall(MethodCallExpression mc) +1368
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression mc) +74
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner(Expression node) +1003
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.Visit(Expression node) +18
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitContains(Expression sequence, Expression value) +377
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitSequenceOperatorCall(MethodCallExpression mc) +9129
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression mc) +74
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner(Expression node) +1003
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.Visit(Expression node) +18
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitExpression(Expression exp) +18
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitWhere(Expression sequence, LambdaExpression predicate) +125
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitSequenceOperatorCall(MethodCallExpression mc) +3403
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression mc) +74
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner(Expression node) +1003
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.ConvertOuter(Expression node) +79
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.BuildQuery(Expression query, SqlNodeAnnotations annotations) +114
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression query) +132
   System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator() +35
   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +7667686
   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +61
   lab_test.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs ee) in d:\Projeler\Kardelen\Kod\Kardelen.Web.UI\lab\test.aspx.cs:543
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +14
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +35
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +99
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +50
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +627
```

Is anybody get this exception?

Thanks for response.

Comment: I had some errors in .Net when using a column of Type DateTime that contained Null values. I don't know about NULL values in Linq but try running your code against a table without NULL values in that column to check. Added: Or see what happens when you "add" -10 years to DateTime.MinValue?

Comment: Not the cause of your problem, but you probably shouldn't use `DateTime.Now.AddYears(-10)` within the `Where` clause. Define it once before so it is the same for all calls. As to your problem, I'm guessing `BirthDate` is simply `null`?

Comment: Steven Jeuris, when I declare DateTime.Now.AddYears(-10) before selection as a variable, the problem is solved. Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If I filter user table using another column, exception is not throwed.
>   DateTime type columns cause this exception.

Assuming you mean this comparison: `c.BirthDate < DateTime.Now.AddYears(-10)`

Most likely `BirthDate` is `null`. In case it is sufficient in your scenario to just skip those users, you can add a check to see whether it is null before doing the date comparison.

As a sidenote, you should probably define `DateTime.Now.AddYears(-10)` once before calling `Where` to prevent it from being recalculated, and worse from the value changing over time.

```
DateTime tenYearsAgo = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-10);
var ids = dc.Users
    .Where(c => c.BirthDate != null && c.BirthDate < tenYearsAgo)
    .Select(c => c.UserId);
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your `c.BirthDate` property is *nullable* , `DateTime? BirthDate`.

That would match an Allow-NULL column in your table.

A simple check should be enough:

```
 dc.Users.Where(c => c.BirthDate.HasValue 
       && (c.BirthDate < DateTime.Now.AddYears(-10))
 )
```